# (Oracle SQL) Problems with joins and pairs of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 Tables

```
CREATE TABLE airships(
    idas number PRIMARY KEY,
    nameas varchar2(20),
    range number
                     );

CREATE TABLE Certificate(
      idem number NOT NULL,
      idas number NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (idem) REFERENCES employees(idem),
      FOREIGN KEY (idas) REFERENCES airships(idas)
                        );


CREATE TABLE employees(
      idem number PRIMARY KEY,
      nameem varchar2(20),
      paycheck number
                    );
```

I have to find pairs of employees who are certified for the same airships with range over 3000.

I know that I have to use JOIN, but I dont know how to find pairs from the same table.

Comment: You have to join with the same table twice.

Comment: Is `airhips` a typo? Shouldn't it be `airships`?

Comment: Sry . It was my spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e1.nameem, e2.nameem, a.nameas
FROM employees e1
JOIN Certificates c1 ON e1.idem = c1.idem
JOIN Certificates c2 ON c1.idas = c2.idas AND c1.idem < c2.idem
JOIN employees e2 ON e2.idem = c2.idem
JOIN airships a ON a.idas = c1.idas
WHERE a.range > 3000
```

The `c1.idem < c2.idem` test keeps it from reporting the employee as a pair with himself, and also avoids showing the same pair twice (in the opposite order).